# Problema con public file en express

Tags: html, css, express

Tengo un problema no puedo hacer que el archivo CSS se aplique en el HTML

Este es mi index.js

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const morgan = require("morgan");
const path = require("path");

    //ROUTES
app.use(require("./routes/routes"));


//STATIC FILES
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname + '/public/css')));
```

Este es mi archivo html

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/server/public/css/index.css" type="text/css">
 </head>
```

Mi path:

```
        /server /index.js
        /public /css /index.css
        /views  /index.html
        /routes /routes.js
```

y mi archivo routes.js

```
const express = require("express");
const routes = express.Router();


routes.get("/",(req,res)=>{
   res.render("index.html")
});

module.exports = routes;
```

¿Alguien sabe por qué no me aplica el CSS?

Answer (score 1):

Al usar `app.use()` con el middleware `express.static(carpeta)` express expone o monta  *carpeta* en el raíz del server.

La línea:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname + '/public/css')));
```

Hace que todos los archivos en `__dirname + '/public/css'` sean accesibles desde `http://localhost:3000/`, es decir que para que funcione el html deberías cambiarlo a:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css" type="text/css">
```

Para tener los css (u otros static files) en su propia carpeta suele ser mas recomendable montarlos en un path predefinido especificando un middleware static para el path ( usando el primer y segundo parámetro de `use` ) , por ejemplo:

`server.js`

```
const IMG_DIR = path.join(__dirname + '/assets/imagenes/');
const CSS_DIR = path.join(__dirname + '/public/css/');

app.use('/img', express.static(IMG_DIR));
app.use('/css', express.static(CSS_DIR));
```

`index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/index.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
  <h1>hola</h1>
  <img src="/img/imagendeprueba.png" />
</body>
</html>
```

> En este ejemplo `imagendeprueba.png` está en la carpeta `assets/imagenes/` pero al estar montada en `/img`, desde el html (el cliente) se accede por `/img/imagendeprueba.png`

Estructura de archivos:

`$ tree express_static/ -L 4 -I node*`

```
express_static/
├── assets
│   └── imagenes
│       └── imagendeprueba.png
├── package-lock.json
├── public
│   └── css
│       └── index.css
├── routes
│   └── routes.js
├── server.js
└── views
    └── index.html
```

Ejemplo completo:

`server.js`

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const morgan = require("morgan");
const path = require("path");

// render engine
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
app.set('view engine', 'html')

//ROUTES
app.use(require("./routes/routes"));


//STATIC FILES
//app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname + '/public/css')));
const IMG_DIR = path.join(__dirname + '/assets/imagenes/');
const CSS_DIR = path.join(__dirname + '/public/css/');

app.use('/img', express.static(IMG_DIR));
app.use('/css', express.static(CSS_DIR));

// server up
app.set('port', 3000);
const server = app.listen(app.get('port'), () =>
  console.log('Example app listening on port '+ server.address().port)
);
```

`views/index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/index.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
  <h1>hola</h1>
  <img src="/img/imagendeprueba.png" />
</body>
</html>
```

packages instalados:

`$ npm ls --depth 0`

```
/home/code/SO/express_static
├── ejs@2.6.1
├── express@4.16.4
├── html@1.0.0
├── morgan@1.9.1
└── path@0.12.7
```